# Can I pull JSON from api url and use as json2html input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json2html

I have working on a webpage that displays json data in a html hierarchical structure, using the jQuery plugin [json2html](http://json2html.com/).

Currently the json data is entered into a text area and a button is pressed to run the conversion. This is the current function that gets the json from the text area  and starts the conversion.

```
    $('#btnVisualize').click(function() {

        //Get the value from the input field
        var json_string = $('#inputJSON').val();


        try
        {
            //json
            //var json = JSON.parse(json_string);

            eval("var json=" + json_string);

            visualize(json);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("Sorry error in json string, please correct and try again: " + e.message);
        }

    });
```

The api that the data is comming from needs a lot of authentication, so I have a seperate javascript file that generates the authenticaton and creates the full url to load the api.

```
function generateUrl(itemkey) {
    var orig = "http://explorerapi.barratthomes.co.uk/v2.0/development/getbyitemkey?ItemKey="+itemkey+"&";
    Auth.Auth = createAuth();
    var var_pairs = [
    {name: "Auth.Utc", val: encodeURI(Auth.Auth.Utc)},
    {name: "Auth.RequestId", val: Auth.Auth.RequestId},
    {name: "Auth.DeviceId", val: Auth.Auth.DeviceId},
    {name: "Auth.Hash", val: Auth.Auth.Hash}];
    for(var i=0; i<var_pairs.length; i++) {
        orig += (i==0?"":"&")+var_pairs[i].name+"="+var_pairs[i].val;
    }
    var var_names = ["BrandCode", "ApplicationId", "ApplicationVersion", "LanguageCode", "IsPublished", "MarketingSuiteDevelopmentId", "UserLocation", "Os", "ScreenResolution", "Hierarchical"];
    for(var j=0; j<var_names.length; j++) {
        orig += "&"+var_names[j]+"="+Auth[var_names[j]];
    }
    return orig;
}
```

This is the function that generates the url.

I need to take the url from that function and connect to the api and pass the data directly to the json2html function, so I no longer have to paste the json data into the text area.

I have been looking at `$.getJson` and `$.parseJSON` but having no luck, I'm not sure where to go next?

Comment: Can you get the json properly

Comment: @siva I've now managed to connect to the api, still working on pull the data from it though

Comment: Did you try with jsonp because you are getting the json from another url , jsonp is used to get the data through cross platform

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jsonp to do the fetching the data from the url

```
function insertIntoTextArea(content) {
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
}

// create script element
var script = document.createElement('script');
 // assing src with callback name
script.src = 'your proper url?callback=insertIntoTextArea';
       // insert script to document and load content
 document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use $.getJSON like this

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});

And then just pass the data object to json2html.  However, check with the API that you're connecting to http://explorerapi.barratthomes.co.uk/v2.0/development/getbyitemkey as they might require JSONP (which pretty much just performs a callback function to get around CORS).

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the >server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion >of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.